# Dynamic SQL to Update One table form Multiple table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table PI_Catalogue_Update which store Schema Name, Table Name, Count(*) as Volume and max(ETLRunTime) as LastUpdate from multiple original tables. How can I build a query which will use the SchemaName and TableName from PI_Catalogue_Update and query over the original tables and update the volume and LastUpdate every time I run the SP.

Probably I need some dynamic SQL. Still I can not figure out how to do.

the table looks like:

```
SchemaName      TableName   Volume     LastUpdate
ProdInsights_In abc         4680816    2017-06-04 00:00:00.000
ProdInsights_In bcd         52250      2017-06-04 00:00:00.000
ProdInsights_In def         744225     2017-06-04 00:00:00.000
ProdInsights_In gih         668502     2017-06-04 00:00:00.000
```

The Query I have written is another way of doing, I have created a view form the original table, [ProdInsights_In].[View_Table_Catalogue].View looks Like:

```
CREATE VIEW  [ProdInsights_In].[View_Table_Catalogue] AS
select
  'ProdInsights_In' as SchemaName
  ,'abc' as TableName
  ,Count(*) Volume
  ,MAX(ETLRunTime) as LastUpdate
From [ProdInsights_In].[abc]
Union All
select
  'ProdInsights_In' as SchemaName
  ,'bcd' as TableName
  ,Count(*) Volume
  ,MAX(ETLRunTime) as LastUpdate
From [ProdInsights_In].[bcd]
Union All ....
```

Then I am using the following SP to Update the PI_Catalogue_Update table from the View.
Procedure looks like:

```
MERGE
INTO    [dbo].[PI_Project_Catalogue] t1
USING   [ProdInsights_In].[View_Table_Catalogue] t2
ON      t1.SchemaName = t2.SchemaName
    and t1.TableName = t2.TableName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     t1.Volume = t2.Volume
       ,t1.LastUpdate = t2.LastUpdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT  (SchemaName, TableName, Volume, LastUpdate)
VALUES  (t2.SchemaName. t2.TableName, t2.Volume, t2.LastUpdate)
```

Comment: I suggest  you use Triggers instead of dynamic queries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql

Comment: Could you please post the query you have written so far?

Comment: I have edited the question section with my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid dynamic sql and use system views to get the row counts instead of executing `select count(*) from ...` for each table.

```
select 
    [SchemaName]= s.name
  , [TableName] = o.name
  , [row_count] = p.rows
from sys.partitions p
  inner join sys.indexes i 
    on p.object_id = i.object_id
      and p.index_id = i.index_id
      and i.index_id < 2
  inner join sys.objects o
    on i.object_id = o.object_id
  inner join sys.schemas s
    on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
where o.is_ms_shipped=0
```

As an update:

```
update picu
    set [Volume] = p.rows
      , [LastUpdate] = sysutcdatetime()
from sys.partitions p
  inner join sys.indexes i 
    on p.object_id = i.object_id
      and p.index_id = i.index_id
      and i.index_id < 2
  inner join sys.objects o
    on i.object_id = o.object_id
  inner join sys.schemas s
    on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
  inner join PI_Catalogue_Update picu
    on picu.SchemaName = s.name
   and picu.TableName  = o.name
```

Reference:

- [Bad habits : Counting rows the hard way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way)

---

To get the `max(ETLRunTime)` using a temporary table and a loop to update with dynamic sql:

```
/* --- get all tables and row count that have `ETLRunDate` column. --- */
create table #tmp (
    id int not null identity(1,1)
  , SchemaName sysname collate Latin1_General_CI_AS -- set collation to match collation of `pi_Project_Catalogue` 
  , TableName  sysname collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
  , Volume bigint
  , LastUpdate date
);
insert into #tmp (SchemaName, TableName, Volume)
select 
    [SchemaName]= s.name
  , [TableName] = o.name
  , [Volume] = p.rows
from sys.partitions p
  inner join sys.indexes i 
    on p.object_id = i.object_id
      and p.index_id = i.index_id
      and i.index_id < 2
  inner join sys.objects o on i.object_id = o.object_id
  inner join sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
where o.is_ms_shipped=0
  and exists (
    select 1
    from sys.columns c
    where c.object_id = o.object_id
      and c.name = 'ETLRunTime'
      )
/* --- loop --- */      
declare @c   bigint = (select max(id) from #tmp);
declare @id  bigint = 1;
declare @sql nvarchar(4000);
declare @params nvarchar(32) = N'@id bigint';
while @id <= @c
begin;
  select @sql = N'
    update #tmp 
      set LastUpdate = (
        select max(ETLRunTime)
        from '+quotename(SchemaName)+'.'+quotename(TableName)+'
      )
    where id = @id;'
  from #tmp where id = @id
  exec sp_executesql @sql, @params, @id;
set @id = @id+1;
end;
/* --- merge --- */
merge into [dbo].[pi_Project_Catalogue] with (holdlock) as tar 
using #tmp as src
  on tar.SchemaName = src.SchemaName
 and tar.TableName  = src.TableName
when matched then update 
  set tar.Volume     = src.Volume
    , tar.LastUpdate = src.LastUpdate
when not matched then insert (SchemaName, TableName, Volume, LastUpdate)
  values (src.SchemaName, src.TableName, src.Volume, src.LastUpdate);
```

Instead of the `merge` that you use, you could do separate statements for update and then insert. I used `merge`, as that is what you have in your question, with the addition of `with (holdlock)`.

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HCOLM75894

returns:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| SchemaName | TableName | Volume |     LastUpdate      |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| dbo        | a         |      1 | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 |
| dbo        | c         |      2 | 06.06.2017 00:00:00 |
| dbo        | d         |      3 | 06.06.2017 00:00:00 |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
```

using this dummy data:

```
create table pi_Project_Catalogue (SchemaName sysname collate Latin1_General_CI_AS, TableName sysname collate Latin1_General_CI_AS, Volume bigint, LastUpdate date)
create table a (id int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered, ETLRunTime date)
insert into  a values ('20170101');
create table b (id int not null identity(1,1) ); -- no ETLRunTime  column
insert into  b default values
create table c (id int not null identity(1,1), ETLRunTime date );
insert into  c values (sysutcdatetime()),(sysutcdatetime());
create table d (id int not null identity(1,1), ETLRunTime date );
insert into  d values (sysutcdatetime()),(sysutcdatetime()),(sysutcdatetime());
```

`merge` reference:

- [Use Caution with SQL Server''s `MERGE` Statement - Aaron Bertrand](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)
- [UPSERT Race Condition With `Merge` - Dan Guzman](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)
- [An Interesting `MERGE` Bug - Paul White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/03/another-interesting-merge-bug.aspx)
- [Can I optimize this `merge` statement - Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/can-i-optimize-this-merge-statement/44069#44069)
- [If you are using indexed views and `MERGE`, please read this! - Aaron Bertrand](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug)
- [The Case of the Blocking `Merge` Statement (LCK_M_RS_U locks) - Kendra Little](https://www.littlekendra.com/2016/05/24/the-case-of-the-blocking-merge-statement-lck_m_rs_u-locks/)
- [Writing t-sql `merge` statements the right way - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/05/writing-t-sql-merge-statements-the-right-way/)

Comment: Hi, It is a nice way of doing. but sysutcdatetime() is always showing me the current datetime, Even I did not update any thing for some table. Actually I have a tool which insert data every day in those tables and the column called ETLRunTime in all the tables updated by the tool. I want to take the `Max(ETLRunTime)` as LastUpdate is it possible some how? 
I have edited the question with the query I have written but the query does not looks good and efficient enough though. Thanks

Comment: @DataPoliceInc. Updated my answer to include the `ETLRunTime`. Somehow missed that when I first read the question.

Comment: Hi, That's a nice way  of doing. Really appreciate your effort . I have learned something new. Thank you..